# Delete ^L character in a log file

Tags: python, unicode

I want to delete all the characters "\L" that I find when i read the file. I tried to use this function when I read a line:

```
def cleanString(self, s):
            if isinstance(s, str):
                    s = unicode(s,"iso-8859-1","replace")
                    s=unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
                    return s.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

But it doesn't delete this character. Does someone know how to do it?

I tried using the `replace` function as well, but it is not better:

```
s = line.replace("\^L","")
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: The Python representation of `^L` is `'\x0c'` or `'\f'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you have not the literal characters `^` and `L`, but something that is displayed as `^L`.

This would be the form feed character.

So do `s = line.replace('\x0C', '')`.

Comment: HO I can't believe that it was that simple. Thank you i was on  that problem since this morning ;)

Answer (score 2):

`^L` (codepoint `0C`) is an ASCII character, so it won't be affected by an encoding to ASCII. You could filter out all control characters using a small regex (and, while you're at it, filter out everything non-ASCII as well):

```
import re
def cleanString(self, s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        s = unicode(s,"iso-8859-1","replace")
        s = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
        s = re.sub(r"[^\x20-\x7f]+", "", s)  # remove non-ASCII/nonprintables
        return str(s)                        # No encoding necessary
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it correct, you just need a different representation for `^L`.

```
s = line.replace("\x0c", "")
```

Here's a function that will return the representation of any control character.

```
def cc(ch):
    return chr(ord(ch) & 0x1f)

>>> cc('L')
'\x0c'
```

Some control characters have alternate representations, the common ones being `'\r'` for `^M` and `'\n'` for `^J`. These are listed in a chart in [the documentation for string literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) based on the name given in an [ASCII control code chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_control_code_chart).